# how to assign unique attribute value per neighborhood?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, polygon, geoprocessing, algorithm

I have a feature class of adjacent polygons and I want to assign an integer attribute value to my polygons based on the following rules :

- a polygon must not have the same attribute value than any of its neighbours
- the number of attribute values must be as small as possible (I don't want to use the FIDs, because I want to convert my polygons to an 8-bit raster, so I can use no more than 256 values)

Here is a small example :

[image]

I am planning to loop on all features, look for neighbours, and assign the smallest possible value, but maybe there is a more efficient algorithm or an existing tool. QGIS and ArcGIS 10.1 solutions are both welcome.

Comment: Maybe this question will help you: [How to apply the four colors theorem in a polygon map in ArcGIS/ArcToolBox automatcally?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54029/how-to-apply-the-four-colors-theorem-in-a-polygon-map-in-arcgis-arctoolbox-autom)

Comment: @Jens : thanks for the link. I didn't know that there was a theorem on this, but this makes my question a duplicate. Should I remove it ?