# Achieving four color theorem for QGIS

Tags: qgis, four-color-theorem

I recently looked at [Applying four colors theorem in polygon map using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54029) which relates to this topic but as far as I can tell there is currently not a working plugin or script for QGIS 2.0 to achieve a four color theorem for styling polygon vector data (it doesn't necessarily have to be 4 colors, just so that each neighboring polygon is a different color, though keeping it at a minimum number of 4-6 colors would be elegant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [TopoColour](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Qgis/Plugins/Documentation/topocolour/) plugin, which is already compatible with QGIS 2.x but is not yet available in the official repository:

https://github.com/nyalldawson/topocolour

Download the zip file and unzip it in the QGIS plugin directory:

- Linux: `~/.qgis2/python/plugins`
- Windows: `C:\Users\{username}\.qgis2\python\plugins`

Answer (score 24):

This is natively supported in QGIS 3.

- View → Panels → Processing Toolbox
- Select Topological coloring
- Set parameters as preferred. Run.
- This will create a new layer with an additional color_id column but still the same color.
- Edit the properties of the new layer, Symbology section.
- At the top, drop down to select Categorized.
- Define the column as color_id.
- Select your color scheme.
- Click Classify to create the categories and assign them the colors.

Comment: As of Qgis 3.26 this does not necessarily achieve 4 colors. In my first test using the counties of NM as the input layer, the algorithm required 5 colors regardless of parameter choices.

Comment: @Llaves, I did check my own maps and got the exact same result with older and latest versions of QGIS. I initially tried a map that required 6 colors but it was the same with the older version of QGIS and it seems that it was required.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the [Map Coloring](https://gitlab.com/Balaitous/mapcoloring) plugin. You need to enable experimental plugins in the Plugin manager to get it, and look for `Coloring a map` in the manager. For some strange reasons, you get a blank icon, so use `Plugins -> Map Coloring -> Map Coloring` from the menu.

The output looks like this, after switching to `Categorized` styling on the `COLORID` field:

[image]