# QGIS 2.x - 4 colors theorem - TopoColour and Map Coloring plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, plugins, colormap

I try to use [TopoColour or Map Coloring plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89015/four-color-theorem-for-qgis-2-0-or-leaflet) to color [my polygon layer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-u7dqmskzd5MmI3elVXZXBIOVk): 
Both of them doesn't work or I do something wrong. Maybe somebody knows any other plugins which color shapes according to 4 color theorem?

Comment: Could you explain why it doesn't work? i.e. are the colours not applied? Does the plugin not load? Does QGIS crash?

Comment: QGIS 3.0 will have a nice [map coloring algorithm](https://nyalldawson.net/2017/02/new-map-coloring-algorithms-in-qgis-3-0/) included. It's not going to help you right now ([3.0 is currently scheduled for release in September 2017](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html#release-schedule)), but something to look forward to!

Comment: Both of them fill the shape by 1 color only, but TopoColour: shows that it found 773 adjacencies, allows add graph layer, shows that 7 colours are needed to color the shape (but this is an error, because we know that we need min. 4 colours).
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-u7dqmskzd5MlB4SnlqaFZWTFU

Comment: i can confirm the **Map colouring** plugin doesn't seem to work on some test data (it always choose 3 colours, it seems). The **TopoColour plugin** works better on my test data, although it uses 5 colours (with both greedy and random colouring)

Answer (score 1):

Map coloring plugin works for my first test shape and it used 4 colors: http://forum.quantum-gis.pl/attachment.php?aid=420