# Political Map Country Fill Colour

Tags: geoserver, style

I'm trying to create a political map from country polygons with GeoServer.

Is there away to assign the countries colors from a defined set of colors without having to assign colors individually?

The result would be so that each neighboring country would be different.

Comment: You could use Natural Earth data - it has MAPCOLOR attributes that you can use directly.

Answer (score 5):

I am unfamiliar with GeoServer but what you are interested in is the [four color theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem).  There is a four color theorem for QGIS at [Achieving four color theorem for QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89015).

There is an Esri approach at [Applying four colors theorem in polygon map using ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54029).

Try adding a new column to your data, populate it with number values from the four color theorem tools, and symbolize off of that column.