# Python, colorize raster randomly avoiding same color for adjacent cells

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, xarray

I'm processing GeoTIFF rasters with python and xarray. The file contains some cells with different values. It looks like that:

[image]

There are about 100 different values in the file and each value needs to get a color for visualization. As you can see, the boundaries are not clearly defined, and there are often some small pixels of one category in the middle of the others

I need a solution to give one color per value in this file and I have to be sure that no adjacent cell gets the same color. I need to work only with python as the visualization will be done in a custom web interface and not in a GIS software
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89015/achieving-four-color-theorem-for-qgis

Comment: This four-color theorem is useful if the polygons are alone. In my case, there is for one value, multiple areas and I'd like to do that directly on the raster layer.