# How to uniquely color polygons with touching boundaries (Block Groups) using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology

I would like to have different colors for block groups that are right next to each other to differentiate them better. I have not found an easy way to do this in ArcGIS Pro. Any ideas?

Comment: A google on "four color theorem arcgis pro" turned up this Q&A here in GIS SE. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54029/how-to-apply-the-four-colors-theorem-in-a-polygon-map-in-arcgis-arctoolbox-autom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5fa04ce288284c999f70464e1c3b2e82

While I haven't tested it, the link above appears to be for a tool that can help you create a "5 color theorem" map. It should assign a value between 1-5 to each block group and then you can assign a color fill for each value. That should mean that no two touching polygons are the same color.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I just added the toolbox through the catalog and I had no issues. I'm working with ArcGIS Pro 2.8.1