# How to ensure different colors for surrounding polygons in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I can symbolize my polygon in ArcGIS by categories. I tried for every field. But unfortunately in few polygon it showing same color those are just beside of same color polygon. I have to categorized 572 polygon. So it will be a hectic task if I have to do this manually. Is there any way to categorized polygons which are not identical in color with the polygons its surrounded?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a common problem in Cartography. There is also an important Mathematical theorem on this, called the [four color theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem)

To use this in ArcMap, there was a sample tool for this, called the [Map Coloring - Four Color a Map"](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14822). If you are still at ArcGIS 9.x, you can use it directly.

If you are at ArcGIS 10, you can still use the tool, by registering with esriRegasm, like this:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\esriregasm.exe" <TargetPath> /p Desktop /v 10.0`

Fore more details, read this Forum post: ["Four Color a Map" for ArcGIS 10](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/29947-quot-Four-Color-a-Map-quot-for-ArcGIS-10)

The following two questions are related:

- [Coloring thousands of polygons so each is distinct from its neighbors?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27101/color-polygons-so-each-is-distinct-from-its-neighbors)
- [How to apply the four colors theorem in a polygon map in ArcGIS/ArcToolBox automatcally?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54029/how-to-apply-the-four-colors-theorem-in-a-polygon-map-in-arcgis-arctoolbox-autom)

Comment: Nice post. The link to the tool is not working anymore and I could not locate the tool in the new ESRI resources/scripts sites. Any ideas?